# sort the most frequent combinations of two columns in descending order

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe that looks like this

```
+---+---+---
|  A|  B| C|
+---+---+---
|  1|  3| 1|
|  2|  1| 1|
|  2|  3| 1|
|  1|  2| 1|
|  3|  1| 1|
|  1|  2| 1|
|  2|  1| 1|
|  1|  3| 1|
|  1|  2| 1|
+---+---+---
```

I want to reduce the data to only the most frequent combinations of two columns (A and B) sorted in descending order
The output should look like

```
+---+---+-----+
|  A|  B|count|
+---+---+-----+
|  1|  2|    3|
|  2|  1|    2|
+---+---+-----+
```

I wrote this code but it does not sort

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data=pd.read_csv("file.csv",sep=',')
gps = data[['A','B','C']]
gps1=gps.groupby(['A','C'])


gps1=gps1.count()
gps1.columns=['count']
gps1.sort_values(['count'],ascending=False)
print(gps1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `sort_values()` back into `gps1` or use `inplace=True:

```
gps1.sort_values(['count'],ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

or

```
gps1 = gps1.sort_values(['count'],ascending=False)
```

As stated in the documentation of [sort_values](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), `inplace` is by default set to `False`

Answer (score 4):

use `nlargest`

```
gps.groupby(['A', 'B']).size().nlargest(2)

A  B
1  2    3
   3    2
dtype: int64
```

or

```
gps.groupby(['A', 'B']).size().nlargest(2).reset_index(name='count')
```

[image]