# Pull most frequent combination of 2 columns from panda dataframe by count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, pandas-groupby

I am relatively new to Python programming.. I have a dataframe, df - from which i need to pull a combination of 2 columns that has most number of occurences

I followed the below thought process
- Did a grouping of dataframe by the requested 2 columns
- Performed a count of rows (hence used axis = 0)that belong to each of those groupings
- Based on the count of rows pulled for each unique group/combination, i tried to sort those rows

Code below

```
output = df.groupby(['column1','column2']).count().sort_values(by=['column1','column2'], axis = 0)[0]

Getting some error like this:
in get_loc return self._engine.get_loc(key)

resulting into this exception:
in get_loc return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
```

Appreciate any help here

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Is it possible to add some example data? Most cases around 5 rows is enough so we can understand what we are looking at.

Comment: Please clarify what type of return you're looking for. "pull a combination of 2 columns that has most number of occurences" doesn't really describe precisely what you need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sort the most frequent combinations of two columns in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40621802/sort-the-most-frequent-combinations-of-two-columns-in-descending-order)

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry - i wasn't able to paste the rows , but what i meant was consider raw data in a csv file that has columns as follows - date (MM/DD/YYYY), start time, end time, duration, start destination, end destination, user type, gender....what i wanted to pull was a (start destination, end destination) combination with maximum number of row entries..i.e. the 'from' <--> to locations that were most traveled. I used the logic i stated below in another thread and it works fine..thanks for taking interest..let me know if you any better thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is being caused by the `[0]` at the end of your line where you do the `groupby`. You didn't post the full error message, but I would bet you have a `KeyError: 0`.  That is due to you no longer having a `0` in your index. If you take a look at the `DataFrame` created after the `groupby` you'll see that you now have a hierarchical index, created from the unique value combinations of `column1` and `column2`.

The quick solution? Replace `[0]` with `.iloc[0]` to get the row in the zero-index-location.

```
output = df.groupby(['column1','column2']).count().sort_values(by=['column1','column2'], axis = 0).iloc[0]
```

Or use `.head(1)`, to get the top row of the `DataFrame`.

Comment: Thanks @kingfischer - you are correct..it was a keyerror :0...i tried using .iloc[0] without doing the grouping and sort..output = df[['column1', 'column2']].mode().loc[0]  to get the most common column combination...if i replace my current query with iloc[0], it works as well..    output = df[['column1', 'column2']].groupby(['column1','column2']).count().sort_values(by=['column1','column2'], axis = 0).iloc[0]

Comment: Great to hear @Shalin! I'll throw in a third option for fun: Call `.reset_index()` after the `.sort_values()`, then you can use `[0]`. This will push the hierarchical index in proper dataframe columns, and reset the index (as the name implies) to numerical, starting at `0`. This trick is probably pointless in this situation, since you already have your desired value on top, but I find myself calling `.reset_index()`after a `.groupby()` quite often when using pandas for other reasons.

Comment: thats awesome @kingifscher, but i just realized, the print statement when i used the original query without reset_index() led to some format issues..i added *reset_index()* after *sort_values()* method and it returns the correct output with formatting issues resolved..However i noticed that i needed to use *.iloc()* ..it didn't work with *[0]* (Got the same error - KeyError:0  -  in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)) ..maybe because i need to pull the actual column and not the whole row